# google analytics demographics intrest overview fetch

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to get all the data from google analytics. Can you please explain how to get data of "isitors-demographics-interest-overview"

1. Affinity Category
2. In-Market Segmen
3. Other Category0.00% of total users

I used some codes to get data from google analatics but i am stuck on "intrest menu"

```
$age = Analytics::performQuery($pobj, 'data', ['metrics' => 'ga:users','dimensions' => 'ga:userAgeBracket']);
$google['age'] = $age;

/*gender*/
$gender = Analytics::performQuery($pobj, 'data', ['metrics' => 'ga:users','dimensions' => 'ga:userGender']);
$google['gender'] = $gender;
```

Answer (score 1):

The google analytics API is not related to the Google analytics website.  The google analytics website has set up reports that have been processed internally.

1. you can not get **ALL** your google analytics data unless you have a premium account in that case you can request that it be exported to BigQuery.
2. You can not get the interest menu report directly. Your going to have to build up the data yourself using the [dimensions and metrics available](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)